# How to iterate over Map in immutablejs

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js

What is the equivalent to `Object.entries()` in Immutablejs Map. Basically, I enumerate the object's key/value pairs to render a presentational component

```
{
  Object.entries(filteredNetworks)
  .map(([key, value]) =><option key={key} value={key}>{value}</option>)
}
```

Now, with the `filteredNetworks` being an immutable Map, how can i do the same ? (without using `.toJS()`)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on: 
https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Iterable/map

```
{
  filteredNetworks.map(
  (value, key) => <option key={key} value={key}>{value}</option>
  )
}
```

note that argument order changed for the mapper function.

Another option using Entry Sequence could be

```
{
   filteredNetworks.entrySeq().map(
     .map(([key, value]) =><option key={key} value={key}>{value}</option>)
   )
}
```

fiddling around at
https://jsfiddle.net/3r866to3/

Answer (score -1):

`Iterable` with method `entries()` would help you.

[Documentation is here](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Iterable/entries)